# Remove auto generated j_id from composite components

Tags: jsf, composite-component

I'm loving the jsf 2.0 composite component setup. One other thing I love is prependId="false" on forms. Is there an equivalent that can be defined in cc:interface or cc:implementation that will prevent jsf from creating a j_id to prepend to the ids defined within the composite component?

Comment: Your question give me the answer: tks for prependId="false" tip

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's not possible. Just give the component a fixed `id` instead letting JSF autogenerate one. The same applies on forms by the way. This way you can still select them using CSS selectors.

Or better, just give them a `styleClass` so that you don't need to select by ID, for the case that this aversion was actually caused by inability to select components/elements by client ID (I don't see other feasible reasons).

Comment: that will work. I get all the html from the creative department and it would be nice to be able to use their ids as delivered but I bet they'll change them up for future projects if I let them know the format.

Comment: Note that the default JSF separator `:` is illegal in CSS. You'd have to escape them as `\3A ` (with space behind). In JSF 2.0 you can however configure it as `javax.faces.SEPARATOR_CHAR` context param in `web.xml`. Use for example `-` (and ensure that you don't use it elsewhere in fixed ids).

Comment: very cool. we have style sheets full of \3A so it would be nice to replace those.

Comment: Very true, but just as a reference: when using jQuery one can select the default colons by escaping them, like `$("#some\\:id").focus();` for `<input id="some:id">`.

Comment: @Arjan: or `$("[id='some:id']")`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927716/how-to-select-primefaces-ui-or-jsf-components-using-jquery/7928290#7928290