# How to select form element and its children in JSF2.0 using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jsf-2

i have a form in JSF2.0 like this

```
    <h:form id="validationFrom" >

        <div id="mandotary" >

            <h:panelGrid columns="4"
                         border="1"
                         width="50%"
                         style=""
                         columnClasses="asteriskColumns, nameColumns" >

                <h:outputLabel value="*" style="color: red;" />
                <h:outputLabel value="Heading: " />
                <h:inputText id="heading" value="#{validation.heading}" />
                <h:message id="headingMessage" for="heading" style="color: red" />

                <h:outputLabel value="*" />
                <h:outputLabel value="Select Category Type :" />
                <h:selectOneRadio id="selectCategoryRadioButton"
                                  rendered=""
                                  value="#{validation.selectedRadioButton}"
                                  layout="layoutDirection">

                    <f:selectItems value="#{validation.radioButtonItems}"/>

                </h:selectOneRadio>
                <h:panelGroup />

                <h:outputLabel value="*"
                               rendered=""/>

                <h:outputLabel value="Broad Category :"
                               rendered=""/>
                <h:selectOneMenu id="broadCategory"
                                 rendered=""
                                 value="#{validation.selectedBroadCategory}" >

                    <f:selectItems value="#{validation.broadCategoryItemsList}"/>

                </h:selectOneMenu>
                <h:message id="broadCategoryMessage" for="broadCategory" style="color: red" />

                <h:outputLabel value="*" />
                <h:outputLabel value="Sub Category :" />
                <h:selectOneMenu id="subCategory"
                                 value="#{validation.selectedSubCategory}"
                                 style="width: 250px;">

                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="---Select---" noSelectionOption="true" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{validation.subCategoryItemsMap}"/>

                </h:selectOneMenu>
                <h:message id="subCategoryMessage" for="subCategory" style="color: red" />

                <h:outputLabel value="*" style="color: red;" />
                <h:outputLabel value="Description: " />
                <h:inputText id="description" value="#{validation.description}" />
                <h:message id="descriptionMessage" for="description" style="color: red" />

            </h:panelGrid>

        </div>

        <h:commandButton id="saveButton"
                         value="Save"
                         action ="null"/>


        <h:commandButton id="cancelButton"
                         value="Cancel"
                         action="null" />

    </h:form>

</h:body>
```

Now i want to select form and div with class mandoroty, so i can check all the elements inside div. I am trying this, but it isn't working

```
(function($){

    var mandotoryFieldsArray = $("#validationFrom div.mandotary")
    var test;

})(jQuery); //end of (function($){}
```

The line is giving me null array. Why? What i am doing wrong in selecting the form element?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select PrimeFaces UI or JSF components using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927716/how-to-select-primefaces-ui-or-jsf-components-using-jquery)

Comment: no, not a duplicate.My id's are not working as you suggested in your post:( I think it's script including issue. I think.... I added comment in the **Hemant Metalia** answer. You can see there. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use

```
$("[@id=validationFrom :mandotary]");
```

refer blog http://rockycode.com/blog/ids-jsf-used-jquery/

Comment: Atleast i sort out one problem, but i don't know what was wrong with that thing. I was including my scripts like **<h:outputScript library="javascripts" name="validation.js"/> **. But when i change it to **<h:outputScript library="javascripts" name="validation.js" target="body"/>** i.e. added target attribute, then my script start working. I don't know what is the effect of adding target=body, because script is still included in the head section of the generated HTML. Anyways but now there is another strange thing happening. I am adding another comment.....see below

Comment: I have <h:panelGrid> in my form with id=formvalidation. When i give id to my **<h:panelGrid id="mandotary">**. And then try one of the following `var $grid = $(document.getElementById('validationForm:mandotary'));`, `var $grid1 = $('[id="validationForm:mandotary"]');`, `var $grid2 = $('#validationForm\\:mandotary');`, then i get nothing. i.e., i get empty array. But when i give my panel grid class, like `<h:panelGrid styleClass="mandotary">`, and then try `var $grid4 = $('.mandotary');`, then i get **table.mandotary**. What i am doing wrong with the ids? in case of class i get element...

Comment: but when i use id i get null. What i am doing wrong with the id's. Is this the script including problem. Do i have to include the script right inside my form? Why this is happening? Thanks