# FancyBox doesn't work inside a h:form

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, fancybox

im having troubles displaying a fancybox window.
I really don't know anything about jquery, i'm giving my first steps, so i hope you be patient.
My example:

```
<h:form>
        <h:outputLink id="example1" value="/Images/Flor1.jpg"  title=""  >
                <h:graphicImage alt="example1" value="/Images/TbnFlor1.jpg" />
        </h:outputLink>
</h:form>
```

The jquery function

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("a#example1").fancybox();
});
```

This doesn't work, if the output link is outside the form, fancybox works. I've been looking an answer to solve this, but still coulnd't find it. I hope you can help me guys, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSF generates HTML. JavaScript/jQuery works with HTML DOM tree only, not with original JSF source code. Open the page in your webbrowser, rightclick it and do a *View Source*. You'll see that the generated HTML `<a>` element in question has its ID prefixed with the ID of the parent `<form>` as generated by JSF `<h:form>`. You need to use exactly that ID in the jQuery selector instead.

So,

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:outputLink id="example1" value="/Images/Flor1.jpg"  title=""  >
        <h:graphicImage alt="example1" value="/Images/TbnFlor1.jpg" />
    </h:outputLink>
</h:form>
```

with

```
$('#form\\:example1').fancybox();
```

or

```
$("[id='form:example1']").fancybox();
```

should do. The `:` is an illegal character in CSS selectors, so it had to be escaped.

Easier is however to work with style classes.

```
<h:outputLink ... styleClass="fancybox" />
```

with

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox();
```

This way you can more easily apply it on future other elements as well without the need to change the jQuery code.

#### See also:

- [How to select JSF components using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927716/how-to-select-primefaces-ui-or-jsf-components-using-jquery)