# Write data on a JSF inputText control through JQuery

Tags: jquery, jsp, jsf

How do I write data on a JSF inputText control inside a form using JQuery?

The objective is to pass data back to the managed bean. If there is some other way of doing it I'm open to suggestions.

This does not work:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText id="list1SortOrder"> </h:inputText>
</h:form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function saveOrder() {
                    $("inputText[id=list1SortOrder]").val("1");
    };
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select PrimeFaces UI or JSF components using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927716/how-to-select-primefaces-ui-or-jsf-components-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to add to Cybernate's answer, you should use asterix sign instead of dollar sign in case of loop table jsf elements.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function saveOrder() {
      $("inputText[id*='list1SortOrder']").val("1");
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`<h:inputText id="list1SortOrder"> </h:inputText>`
will generate html as below:
`<input id="form:list1SortOrder" name="form:list1SortOrder" type="text" />`

You need to use ends with selector: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/
Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function saveOrder() {
       $("inputText[id$='list1SortOrder']").val("1");
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Yes indeed it's true, this HTML gets generated:
`<input id="j_id_id122:list1SortOrder" type="text" name="j_id_id122:list1SortOrder">`

and based on the post that @BalusC pointed out, the code that really works on my page is, as replied by @Cybernate and @Tarun Sapra: 


`$("input[id$='list1SortOrder']").val("1");`

and 


`$("input[id*='list1SortOrder']").val("1");`

What is the difference between the * and $ symbols in the id reference?

Comment: @BirdOfPrey : * will match the term anywhere in the id value where as $ will match the term only at the end of the id value. http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/