# Bug in a delete button in JSF page

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, jsf-2, jquery-dialog

I'm trying to implement JSF table with delete button. This is the JavaScript which displays the dialog:

```
function dialog(a){              
    $("<div />", {
        text: a
    }).dialog({        
        width: 600,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function() { 
                $("#myHiddenButtonID").click();
                $(this).dialog("close"); 
            }, 
            "Cancel": function(event) { 
                $(this).dialog("close");
                event.preventDefault();
            } 
        }
    });

}
```

I use second hidden button to delete the rows when the user confirms from the dialog:

```
<!-- hidden button -->
<h:commandButton id="myHiddenButtonID" value="DeleteHiddenButton" action="#{bean.deleteSelectedIDs}" style="display:none">
    <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>

<!-- the button -->
<h:commandButton value="Delete">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" onevent="dialog('demo test')"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
```

When I click on the delete button the dialog appears to confirm the deletion of the table rows. Then I click YES nothing happens. I suppose that the hidden button id is the problem but when I try to fix it nothing happens. The managed bean method is not called.

Comment: can u post how the form is defined in your page

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927716/how-to-select-primefaces-ui-or-jsf-components-using-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in the firebug or view source on you hidden button , look at its complete id , it might be with some prefix like `form1ID:myHiddenButtonID` or some other prefix, if thats the case you should write a better `id` (form1ID:myHiddenButtonID  for example)

like this

```
$("#form1ID\\:myHiddenButtonID").click();
```

also, you can remove the `style="display:none"` from that button and click it manually to see that its really functioning as expected...

You also can try the [Attribute Ends With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

like this

```
$('input[id$="myHiddenButtonID"]').click();
```

Comment: this is the id into the HTML page: `id="form:myHiddenButtonID"`. But when I change the JavaScript this way `$("#form:myHiddenButtonID").click();` thee dialog freezes. When I click on the YES button I can't close it

Comment: Is there any other "name" like `id` that I can assign to the hidden button and call it from the JavaScript?

Comment: try  $('input[id$="myHiddenButtonID"]').click(); and you don't need to have `execute="@form"` in both buttons only in the visible one

Comment: By the way, how this code `$('input[id$="myHiddenButtonID"]').click();` works?

Comment: edited my answer with a link to that specific jQuery Selector, also you better remove the execute attribute in the visible button...

Comment: I removed `render="@form" execute="@form"` from the visible button. Now it's working fine.

Comment: better `execute="@form"` in visible and `render="@form"` in hidden... (just like in my original answer to your confirm dialog question)

Comment: Thanks to @BalucS for the edit... i Forgot that you need to add \\ before the :myHiddenButtonID... that's why $("#form1ID:myHiddenButtonID").click();
 didn't worked for you

Comment: I tested the example with `$('input[id$="myHiddenButtonID"]').click();`. It works very well. I'm going to work with it. I suppose that there is no big difference.

Comment: I'll tell you the difference and you will decide... $('input[id$="myHiddenButtonID"]') selector selects all input element with id that ends with myHiddenButtonID , so if you got some othe button with id="somePrefixmyHiddenButtonID" it will be selected by the selector too, and it will be clicked too... while the $("#form1ID:myHiddenButtonID") selector will select a specific button and click it only...

Comment: Yes, it's better to use $("#form1ID:myHiddenButtonID")

Comment: oops , I meant  `$("#form1ID\\:myHiddenButtonID")` with the `\\`