# Reset password using jQuery/Javascript in JSF login dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

I need advice on how to use jQuery / Javascript for resetting the password after a wrong login using `JSF` + `PrimeFaces` dialog.

```
<p:dialog header="Login" id="loginDlgId" widgetVar="loginDlg" >
    <h:form id="loginForm">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Username:" />
            <p:inputText value="#{loginBean.username}" id="username" required="true" label="username" />
            <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password:" />
            <h:inputSecret value="#{loginBean.password}" id="password" required="true" label="password" />
            <p:commandButton value="Login" id="loginDlgButton" update=":loginButtonForm" 
                                action="#{loginBean.login}" 
                                oncomplete="handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args)"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args) {
        if(args.validationFailed || !args.loggedIn) {
            jQuery('#loginDlgId').effect("shake", { times:3 }, 100);
            if (!args.validationFailed) {
                $('#loginForm:password').html('');  // this doesn't have any effect
                jQuery('#loginForm:password').text('');   // this doesnt' have any effect, too
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

As you can see, in the Javascript function `handleLoginRequest` I have made 2 efforts to reset the password text, but with no result (and appearently no error either). Additionally, any link / reference to give some light in using jQuery in this situation, would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a space between `#loginForm` and `:password` in the selector, and use [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method to reset password value:

```
$("#loginForm :password").val("");
```

Space in the selector actually makes search for `:password` element in `#loginForm`.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Is this a jQuery feature? I have been working on Dojo, but have never seen such a thing as a space in the selector.

Comment: @perissf Well, it works in the same way as JQuery [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method. BTW, make sure to remove `!` before `args.validationFailed` in your `if` statement. Otherwise, it won't work ever :)

Comment: @perissf I can't answer for sure is that **only** JQuery feature, since I haven't ever worked with Dojo. But I can definitely state that JQuery works in this way.

Comment: The coincidence and confusion is here that `:password` in jQuery selects all `<input type="password">` elements and that perissf has given it an `id="password"`. But to select the real element by ids ID, the ID has to be escaped. See also Daniel's answer and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927716/how-to-select-primefaces-ui-or-jsf-components-using-jquery

Comment: @BalusC It is really coincidence :) I have already found the problem with colon, however I haven't faced it by myself. The only thing, I doubt that `html` method works for `input` fields in JSF :) At least from this side my answer should be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Add `\\` before the `:`

Your selector should look like this `'#loginForm\\:password'`

INMO `'#loginForm\\:password'` is more efficient (fast) than `"#loginForm :password"` (but this is my personal thoughts)

**Explanation**

> The presence of : (colon) causes problem to JQuery. So, we need to escape : (colon) using two \ characters before colon

Comment: That's an interesting issue. Where can I read about `\\\` in JQuery selector?

Comment: Well... jQuery don't like the : (colon) that JSF uses between the ids... edited my answer