# jsf2.0 richfaces 4.0 Jquery how to get inputfield value

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, richfaces

I am using JSF2.0 with Richfaces 4.x i am trying to get input myfield value using jquery ?

```
<h:outputScript name="jsf.js" library="javax.faces" />
    <h:outputScript name="jquery.js" />

    <h:outputScript target="head">
    $ = jQuery;
    // Then you can use it
    $(document).ready(function() {
    });
</h:outputScript>

<h:inputText id="myfield" value="#{dataTableBean.name}" label="Name Field">

<input type="button" onclick="javascript:myfun()" value="click me" />



<h:outputScript target="head">
    function myfun(){
    alert($('#myfield').val());
    }
 </h:outputScript>
```

Comment: this is my first project with jsf richfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSF runs in webserver and generates HTML. Webserver sends it to webbrowser. JavaScript runs in webbrowser and all it sees/understands is HTML only.

Open the JSF page in browser. Rightclick and *View Source*. Locate the HTML `<input type="text">` element which is generated by JSF `<h:inputText>`. Look at its `id` attribute. It'll look something like this

```
<input type="text" id="formid:myfield" />
```

You need to use **exactly** that ID in the JavaScript.

```
alert($('#formid\\:myfield').val());
```

#### See also:

- [How to select JSF components using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927716/how-to-select-primefaces-ui-or-jsf-components-using-jquery/7928290#7928290)

Comment: i don't have form name and some times i am not using form element.

Comment: Just give the `<h:form>` an `id`. And in cases when you don't use it, just don't specify the prefix then. Again, look at the generated HTML output. You need to base your JavaScript/code on the HTML source, not on the JSF source.