# Show p:selectOneMenu description in p:outputLabel

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have a .xhtml file with `p:selectOneMenu` and `p:outputLabel` inside. `p:selectOneMenu` is populated from the bean with `f:selectItems`. In the bean it is a `List<SelectItem>` where SelectItems have value, label and description.
My goal is to show description of the selected item in the `p:outputLabel` without making an ajax call to the bean. I can only find values in the DOM tree. I believe it is stored somewhere and I can access it with JS or use some JSF tools.

Comment: So your basic question is like formulated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891586/get-selected-value-from-selectonemenu-using-javascript-in-primefaces-and-open-a . I used google with these terms to find this 'duplicate' :  ["stackoverflow get selected value of selectonemenu primefaces javascript"](https://www.google.nl/search?q=stackoverflow+get+selected+value+of+selectonemenu+primefaces+javascript)

Comment: Yes, but I want to get a description. The problem is that my HTML ouput has a `<select>` with some `<option>` that doesn't have anything except values and labels. And I think there should be a description somewhere.

Comment: description == label from what I know... If you think differently, create an mcve

Answer (score 0):

in the method where this list there can declare a String variable that you capture the selected data and then can call on the label of XHTML

Comment: But can I make it without an ajax call?

Comment: I think if you need the ajax when value change is simply a change event , but you can try