# ui repeat separator char

Tags: jsf-2, uirepeat

Using jsf2 (see **maven dependencies**)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.14</version>
    </dependency>
```

I found out that configuration of jsf doesn't be used by ui:repeat tag. If I redefine the separator char in **web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.SEPARATOR_CHAR</param-name>
    <param-value>_</param-value>
</context-param>
```

a **<ui:repeat>** renderes a **:** anyway, this is why I can't use jquery for finding a div's Id in my custom component:

```
    <a href="#" onclick="toggleDiv('#{cc.clientId}Div')">
      <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.value}" />
    </a>
    <div id="#{cc.clientId}Div" style="display: none">...</div>
```

The HTML result of this component is:

```
    <a href="#" onclick="toggleDiv('j_idt12:0_j_idt18_0_j_idt24Div')">123456</a>
    <div id="j_idt12:0_j_idt18_0_j_idt24Div" style="display: none">
    ...
    </div>
```

As you can see, there's a : in j_idt12:0_j... that makes jquery functions invalid. What can I do about it? Is there a way to set a special ui separator char?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to the jQuery "problem", just escape `:` as `\\:` or use the `[id]` selector instead. See also [How to select JSF components using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927716/how-to-select-primefaces-ui-or-jsf-components-using-jquery/7928290#7928290) By the way, I'd rather use fixed IDs instead of relying on JSF-generated IDs, otherwise your webapp is highly unportable.

As to the `<ui:repeat>` problem, sorry, I can't reproduce it. But that Facelets 1.x dependency is highly suspicious. It would possibly only conflict with Facelets 2.x which is already bundled in JSF 2.x which in turn can indeed explain this problem. Get rid of that Facelets 1.x dependency altogether, you don't need it when already using JSF 2.x.

Comment: Very big thanks for this reply, it helped me much! I decided to use jquerys $('[id="' + id + '"]') to find the element. This works great. Also removed facelets 1 without any problems.