# How to focus on input during a page load using jquery with JSF

Tags: jquery, jsf, focus

When i construct my input manually i can focus on it however when i use a JSF tag to generate my inputs the form name is appended to the id and i can't reference it anymore.

I've tried

```
$("#username").focus();
```

and

```
$("#loginForm:username").focus();
```

without any luck. Any advise?

here is generated jsf html:

```
<input id="loginForm:username" type="text" name="loginForm:username" size="30" />
```

This is my how i'm triggering the call...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("checkA");
    $("#username").focus();
    alert("checkB");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:` is a special character in CSS identifiers. You need to escape it by `\`. Note that the `\` is by itself also a special character in JavaScript strings, so to represent the actual `\`, you need to double-escape it as `\\`.

So, this should do:

```
$("#loginForm\\:username").focus();
```

#### See also:

- [How to select JSF components using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927716/how-to-select-primefaces-ui-or-jsf-components-using-jquery/7928290#7928290)

Comment: nice, works like a charm! If i ever win the lottery i'll make sure a decent portion of it goes to the BalusC trust fund :)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$("input[name*='loginForm']").focus();
```