# Check All Radio Buttons (JSF Component) + jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, dom

I've a form in which I'm iterating a datatable, each row has a set of components and one of them is:

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="chargeWaive" onclick="alert(this.id);" >              <f:selectItem itemLabel="Charge" itemValue="charge" />                  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Waive" itemValue="waive" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

I've added two links that triggers two similar functions :

```
<a href="#" onclick="selectAllCharge();">
   <h:outputText value="Charge All" />
</a>

<a href="#" onclick="selectAllWaive();">
   <h:outputText value="Waive All" />
</a>
```

So when the user clicks on one these links, all the Charge/Waive radiobuttons should be checked.

I've tried to check the first radio button (test purpose) by using one the following codes, but I always get the same error:

```
$('#frmResults:billingRecordId:0:chargeWaive:0').attr('checked', true);   $('#frmResults:billingRecordId:0:chargeWaive:0').attr('checked', 'checked');
$('#frmResults:billingRecordId:0:chargeWaive:0').prop("checked", true);
```

The error that I'm getting is: **Sintax error, unrecognized expression: billingRecordId**

I do know the id is correct because when I look into the compiled JSF code the generated ID for the **radio** type is:

```
<input type="radio" name="frmResults:billingRecordId:0:chargeWaive" id="frmResults:billingRecordId:0:chargeWaive:0" value="charge" onclick="alert(this.id);" /><label for="frmResults:billingRecordId:0:chargeWaive:0"> Charge</label>

<input type="radio" name="frmResults:billingRecordId:0:chargeWaive" id="frmResults:billingRecordId:0:chargeWaive:1" value="waive" onclick="alert(this.id);" /><label for="frmResults:billingRecordId:0:chargeWaive:1"> Waive</label>
```

So at this point I don't know what I'm missing here. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery uses [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors) to select elements in the HTML DOM tree.

The `:` is a special character in the CSS selector representing the start of [structural pseudo class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#structural-pseudos). So if you use

```
$('#frmResults:billingRecordId')
```

then it's basically looking for a HTML element with ID of `frmResults` and having a pseudo class matching `billingRecordId`. However, as `billingRecordId` is not a valid pseudo class at all, nothing will be found.

You'd basically need to escape the colon in CSS selector syntax.

```
$('#frmResults\\:billingRecordId\\:0\\:chargeWaive\\:0')
```

Or, IMO cleaner, use the `[id]` attribute selector.

```
$('[id="frmResults:billingRecordId:0:chargeWaive:0"]')
```

Or, to get rid of the chained IDs and indexes.

```
$('[id$=":chargeWaive"]:first :radio:first')
```

*("select elements with ID ending on `:chargeWaive`, get the first, then get the first radio button from it")*

#### See also:

- [How to select JSF components using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927716/how-to-select-primefaces-ui-or-jsf-components-using-jquery/7928290#7928290)

---

As a completely different alternative, you can also perform a JSF ajax call to preselect the desired radiobuttons by just setting the model value accordingly in the backing bean's ajax listener method.

Comment: Thank you BalusC! Basically I was not escaping the colon (I didn't knew this). I guess every day we learn something new :)

Answer (score 1):

Colons can cause problems within jquery selectors.  Try escaping them with a double backslash ala:

```
$('#frmResults\\:billingRecordId\\:0\\:chargeWaive\\:0').attr('checked', true);
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your solution and it works pretty well, now I know that I need to escape the colons.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this way

Also use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

```
$('[id^="frmResults:billingRecordId:0:chargeWaive:"]').prop("checked", true);
```