# Add a method to input hidden field value

Tags: javascript, jsf-2

Based on the value of the inputHidden field, certain functionality should be performed on the javascript side.

```
<h:inputHidden id="onlyCaseSensitive" value="#{testBean.isPageAllowed()}"/>
```

Afer the javascript is executed, the application throws an error 
Property not qritable Illegal Syntax for Set Operation

Comment: JavaScript runs on the CLIENT, so your server-side goes isn't really much help in this case.

Comment: What are you doing in JavaScript? Are you changing a value of hidden field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *the application throws an error Property not writable Illegal Syntax for Set Operation*

Your EL expression `#{}` is invalid. It must evaluate as a value expression, not as a method expression. It isn't possible to perform a setter method call on the given method expression, while that's required when the JSF form is to be submitted. You need to remove the `is` prefix and those parentheses to make it a valid value expression.

```
<h:inputHidden id="onlyCaseSensitive" value="#{testBean.pageAllowed}"/>
```

This requires a `public boolean isPageAllowed()` getter method and a `public void setPageAllowed(boolean pageAllowed)` setter method.

---

If you *actually* only need to use the JSF managed bean property as a JavaScript variable, then you shouldn't be rendering it as a hidden input at all, but just let JSF render a fullworthy JavaScript variable without the need to mess with hidden inputs and HTML DOM traversal.

E.g.

```
<script>
    var onlyCaseSensitive = #{testBean.pageAllowed};
</script>
```

This will end up in the JSF generated HTML output like as follows (rightclick page and do *View Source* to see it):

```
<script>
    var onlyCaseSensitive = true;
</script>
```

Comment: How can we access this field in javascript? $('#inputText').live("click focus", function(e) {
 if($('#inpText').val()== onlyCaseSensitive){

Comment: Just look in the generated HTML source for the right element ID. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927716/how-to-select-primefaces-ui-or-jsf-components-using-jquery/7928290#7928290

Comment: and if I need to pass 2 arguments to isPageAllowed ?

Answer (score 1):

Value of your `h:inputHidde` should point to the property of backing bean with getter and setter. So, probably when you submit your page there is a problem accessing setter field.