# How do i refer to a jsf object with jquery?

Tags: jquery, jsf

i want to get a textbox object with jquery.

```
$(function() {
    // create a datepicker with default settings
    $("[id='#{fbForm.beginDate}']").mobiscroll().date({
        invalid: {
            daysOfWeek: [0, 6], 
            daysOfMonth: ['5/1', '12/24', '12/25']
        }, 
        theme: 'android-ics light', 
        display: 'bottom', 
        mode: 'scroller', 
        dateOrder: 'mmD ddyy'
    });
});
```

This does not work? Why what is the problem

Comment: In what way does it "not work"?

Comment: also, you could show an example of the object you're trying to get.

Comment: i just want to get the textbox object created with jsf by id

Comment: you can access jsf component jquery by ID : `$('formId\\:textboxId').mobiscroll`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select PrimeFaces UI or JSF components using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927716/how-to-select-primefaces-ui-or-jsf-components-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Assumming you have

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <h:inputText id="myText" />
</h:form>
```

You can access to the component with jQuery using

```
var myText = $('#myForm\\:myText');
```

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    window.onload = function() {
        var myTextValue = $('#myForm\\:myText').val();
        alert(myTextValue);
    };
    //]]>
</script>

<h:form id="myForm">
    <h:inputText id="myText" value="#{fbForm.beginDate}" />
</h:form>
```

Or you can use plain component ID by adding `prependId="false"` on `<h:form>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    window.onload = function() {
        var myTextValue = $('#myText').val();
        alert(myTextValue);
    };
    //]]>
</script>

<h:form prependId="false">
    <h:inputText id="myText" value="#{fbForm.beginDate}" />
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you're using RichFaces you can also use:

**rich:clientId(id)** - returns client Id for component by it's short id.

**rich:element(id)** - returns DOM element for the passed short id

**rich:component(id)** - returns richfaces client component instance to call some API method.

**rich:isUserInRole(role)** - returns if the user has specified role.

**rich:findComponent(id)** - returns component instance for given short id

**rich:jQuery(id)** - returns a jQuery object with an element for given short id

Example:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText id="input">
        <a4j:ajax render="out" />
    </h:inputText>
    <h:outputText value="#{rich:findComponent('input').value}" id="out" />
</h:form>
```

More info and examples on how to do this:

http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=functions&skin=blueSky

Regards,