# reload a JSF tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I need reload a JSF component when press a key, i have the following code

```
<script>
    document.onkeypress=teclaPulsada
    function teclaPulsada()
    {
    var teclaASCII=event.keyCode
    var teclaCHAR=String.fromCharCode(teclaASCII)
    if (teclaASCII==49 )
    {   
    document.getElementById("formularioImagen").setAttribute("value", "TiffBean.getImagen()")
    }
    else if ( teclaASCII==50)
    {
    alert("disminuir")
    }
    }
</script>
<h:form id="formularioImagen">
        <p:graphicImage  id="imagen" value="#{TiffBean.getImagen()}" width="1000" height="1500" border="5" cache="FALSE" >
        </p:graphicImage>
</h:form>
```

when I run the image no reload

Answer (score 2):

you can use `p:remoteCommand` for it.

```
<p:remoteCommand name="refreshImage" process="@this" update="formularioImagen:imagen"/>
```

and in your javascript code, you can do the following:

```
if (teclaASCII == 49)
{   
    refreshImage();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to "re-render" the graphicImage component or one of its parents. An easy way would be to add

```
<p:commandButton id="hiddenBtn" update="formularioImagen:imagen" style="visibility: hidden"/>
```

to the form and have your Javascript select and click the button when a key is click

Comment: HI, thanks for your answer but I need that the image "re-render" when press a key, I can't use buttons

Comment: @oriaj "have your Javascript select and click the button when a key is click" part of the answer refers to your case, but since there is no applicable example provided, you can have a look at here about selecting the component: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927716/how-to-select-primefaces-ui-or-jsf-components-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Primefaces hotkey](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/hotkey.xhtml). It's purpose-built  for this. In your case:

```
<h:form id="formularioImagen">
    <p:graphicImage  id="imagen" value="#{TiffBean.getImagen()}" width="1000" height="1500" border="5" cache="FALSE" >
    </p:graphicImage>
    <p:hotkey bind="ctrl+shift+s" update="imagen"/>
</h:form>
```