# Manipulate DataTable in JQuery in JSF

Tags: jquery, jsf, datatable

How do I redraw or destroy a datatable I declare in my xhtml. I tried everything but it simply doesnt work.

This is my DataTable:

```
<h:dataTable  id= "book" var="book" value="#{bean.booksByAuthor}" rowClasses="even-row,odd-row">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Title</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{book.title}" class=""/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">ISBN</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{book.ISBN}"/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Price</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{book.price}"/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <h:commandButton value="Buy" action="buyItem">
                        <f:param name="book2Buy" value="#{book.ISBN}" />
                    </h:commandButton>
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
```

And this is how I am trying to access it in my script:

```
<script>
        function change() {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#f:\\book').DataTable().clear();
            $('#f:\\book').DataTable().destroy();
        }
    </script>
```

These are my imports:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <!--    Data Table-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-2.2.4/dt-1.10.15/datatables.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-2.2.4/dt-1.10.15/datatables.min.js"></script>
```

I even tried accessing the table like this `$("$book)` and calling `html` or `append` to it. But nothing works. I don't even get any errors.

Any suggestions/recommendations?

Comment: First of all, read [How to select JSF components using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927716/how-to-select-jsf-components-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

If you try to get the element with jquery `$('#f:\\book')` isn't gonna work cause you are looking for an id called f:\book .

If you want to get the datatable in jQuery you should try the selector book directly

```
function change() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#book').DataTable().clear();
    $('#book').DataTable().destroy();
}
```

Also remove the space in between id= and "book"

Comment: If the `<h:datatable id="book"...>` is in an `<h:form id="f">`, the actual client-side id is of the datatable is `f:book`. The ':' needs to be escaped and that is most likely what the OP tried in a wrong way with using `#f:\\book`